# How to read a xml having list of elements not enclosed in parent tag

Tags: java, xml, spring, jackson

How to read a xml having list of elements which are not enclosed in parent tag example of Xml file is as below. In this example it is a list of students which is not enclosed in any of the parent tags. Kindly help me to read this file and extract data using Jackson parser

```
<Student>
    <name>John</name>
    <class>
        <section>A</section>
    </class>
    <subject>English</subject>
</Student>
<Student>
    <name>Johny</name>
    <class>
        <section>B</section>
    </class>
    <subject>Science</subject>
</Student>
<Student>
    <name>Rock</name>
    <class>
        <section>C</section>
    </class>
    <subject>Mathematics</subject>
</Student>
```

Comment: Could this help ?
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization

Comment: Wrap it with an element to make it well-formed before trying to read in with XML APIs. `"<doc>" + Files.readAllLines(studentDoc) + "</doc>"`

Answer (score 0):

> In your POJO class (Example.class), define list of students which is not enclosed in any of the parent tags as below.

```
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
```

> Now in your another class where you are parsing this xml use this

```
String xmlString = "<Student>...</Student>";
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
Example value = xmlMapper.readValue(xmlString, Example.class);
```

> Add maven dependency to the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion... If I follow the same procedure as suggested above I am getting empty Student arrayList without data being populated.